# How can i check the value from NSDictionary and integer values are same?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

i have a dictionary with values as shown in photo,i have integer value of book id  . how can i check whether the bookid 's matching or not?[image]

this is my checking codes

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:metaDataPath];
NSMutableArray *notes=[plistdictionary objectForKey:@"usernotes"];
NSLog(@"notes value %@",notes);
NSArray *CollectingBookid=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingBookid=[notes valueForKey:@"bookid"];
NSArray *CollectingPages=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingPages=[notes valueForKey:@"pagenumber"];
NSArray *CollectingNotes=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingNotes=[notes valueForKey:@"notes"];
NSLog(@"collection of book id%@",CollectingBookid);
NSString *bookid=@"95";
NSString *page=@"1";
int c=[CollectingBookid count];
for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
{
    NSString *singleBookids=[CollectingBookid objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *singlePage=[CollectingPages objectAtIndex:i];
    if([singleBookids isEqualToString:bookid])
        {
            if([singlePage isEqualToString:page])
            {
                NSMutableArray *CompleteUserNotes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                CompleteUserNotes=[CollectingNotes objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"Selected Notes%@",CompleteUserNotes);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why bookid is string in pList? You want to compare integer with integer right ? or you want to compare string with string ?

Comment: how can i add integer value in dictionary?

Comment: These do not match your picture:  NSArray *CollectingBookid=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingBookid=[notes valueForKey:@"bookid"];
NSArray *CollectingPages=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingPages=[notes valueForKey:@"pagenumber"];
NSArray *CollectingNotes=[[NSArray alloc]init];
CollectingNotes=[notes valueForKey:@"notes"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a predicate and find the userNote by filtering array

```
/*As your plist has bookId as string its taken as string. 
But if you have bookId as integer before checking 
convert it to string for predicate to work*/
NSInteger bookId = 92;
NSString *bookIdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",bookId];

NSInteger pageNumber = 12;
NSString *pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pageNumber];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookid == %@ AND pagenumber == %@",bookIdString,pageNumberString];

//filteredUserNotes will have all notes matching bookId
NSArray *filteredUserNotes =  [notes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//Assuming you only has one entry for bookId and you want a single one
NSDictionary *userNote = [filteredUserNotes lastObject];
```

Comment: @Naveen You want to find a userNote item matching bookId rite. In this code you create a predicate which will find matching notes with bookId equal to the one you provided in the predicate. On filtering the result is array, you then take that result and do what you want

Comment: but i want pagenumber and bookid matchings!!

Comment: @Naveen I have edited the code. Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: if i give my inputs instead of your hard coded bookid and page number,u r saying that i dont need to check all the conditions instead i can use predicates thaere?

Comment: @Naveen Yes you are correct. I hardcoded the values just to show you.

Answer (score 2):

Your doing correct comparison by using string  formate.

if  you want to compare with integer use the below code:

```
int bookid=95;
int page=1;
int c=[CollectingBookid count];
for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
{
    NSString *singleBookids=[CollectingBookid objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *singlePage=[CollectingPages objectAtIndex:i];
    if([singleBookids intValue]==bookid)
    { 
        if([singlePage intValue]==page)
        {
            NSMutableArray *CompleteUserNotes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            CompleteUserNotes=[CollectingNotes objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Selected Notes%@",CompleteUserNotes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm write this in notepad. Sorry for possible errors.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *plistdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:metaDataPath];
NSMutableArray *notes=[plistdictionary objectForKey:@"usernotes"];
int bookid = 95;
int page = 1;
for (NSDictionary *collectingObject in notes)
{
    int collectingBookid = [[collectingObject objectForKey:@"bookid"] intValue];
    int collectingPageid = [[collectingObject objectForKey:@"pagenumber"] intValue];
    if (collectingBookid == bookid && collectingPageid == page)
    {
        NSString *collectingNote = [collectingObject objectForKey:@"notes"];
        NSLog(@"Note is: %@", collectingNote);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i convert integer to string?

Comment: int number = 100500;
NSString *stringFromInteger = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to compare integer value

```
[singleBookids intValue]==[bookid intValue];
```